# Remote Access with Powershell and Jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins, winrm

I am trying to run a powershell script on a remote (Windows 2008 Server R2) machine. The following code works great when executed directly from powershell. (I.e. everything is set up correctly, WinRM services are running, Hosts trust each other, login is correct...)

However, when I execute the exact same code from a Jenkins instance (running on the same machine where I tested) I get a **PSSessionStateBroken** connection failure, . (Not posting full error because it is in German on my machine.)

I suppose that means Jenkins is using powershell differently or has different powershell/winrm settings or insufficient privileges. Any ideas?

```
$computer = "<some ip>"
$user = "Administrator"
$password = "<secretpassword>"
$securepassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user, $securepassword
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock { Get-ChildItem C:\ } -Credential $cred
```

**Edit:** Managed to fix it by running jenkins service as Administrator. Works for me, but does not feel right...

Answer (score 4):

As of March 2014, Jenkins installs the Jenkins service to run as the LocalSystem user (i.e.,  `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`).  The LocalSystem account [accesses the network using the computer account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

For example , Jenkins on a host named `JENKINSSERVER` connects to remote machines using the `MYDOMAIN\JENKINSSERVER$` computer account in the `MYDOMAIN` Active Directory domain.

This means you need to add the `MYDOMAIN\JENKINSSERVER$` account as a member of the `BUILTIN\Administrators` local group on the `TARGETSERVER`:

`NET LOCALGROUP "Administrators" "MYDOMAIN\MYSERVER$" /add`

*Caveat Emptor*: This grants any code executing as LocalSystem or NetworkService on the MYSERVER host to run remote commands on `TARGETSERVER` as an Administrator.  You may be better off creating a specific domain user for just this service to restrict admin rights to just the single Jenkins service.

Comment: This is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 1):

Does your Jenkins service account credential have permission to log on remotely to the target computer?

I would use ProcMon to watch the target system when accessed by the administrator account and by the regular service account. You will see a difference, and I bet it will be obvious! Good luck!